# Nested Enum Style and Convention

Tags: c#, convention

I have an enum that controls the way a class operates. This enum is only applicable to the class, and as a result feels like it should be nested. However, that class needs an instance of the enum as a member, which ideally would be named identically to the enum. Of course, this is not possible.

My primary concern is providing a clean and clear API. The two options I see are:

Nest the enum and name either the instance member or the enum itself something that is 'less than perfect'

Put the enum outside the class, which kind of sort of but not really pollutes the namespace, and may reduce discover-ability. (Writing this now, it strikes me that discover-ability is likely not a concern, since there is a single usage point, a property).

Is there an accepted convention for cases such as this? Here's a snippet illustrating the use case:

```
public class MultiModeActionFacadeObject : IAction
{
    public enum ActionMode // enum only applies to this class
    { 
        Fast,
        Accurate,
        Intermediate
    }

    private readonly IAction _accurate, _fast, _intermediate;

    internal MultiModeActionFacadeObject(IAction fastAction, IAction accurateAction, IAction intermediateAction)
    {
        _fast = fastAction;
        _accurate = accurateAction;
        _intermediate = intermediateAction;

    }

    // preference would be to call this member ActionMode, but obviously members can't share names
    // although I believe this could be accomodated, outside of static members, by some changes to 
    // qualification requirements. That's not the concern here though.
    public ActionMode Mode { get; set; } 

    public void DoWork(object onThis)
    {
        switch (Mode)
        {
            case ActionMode.Fast:
                _fast.DoWork(onThis);
                break;
            case ActionMode.Accurate:
                _accurate.DoWork(onThis);
                break;
            case ActionMode.Intermediate:
                _intermediate.DoWork(onThis);
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Generally (in my experience) `enum`s should be suffixed with `Type`. (`ActionModeType`) This is merely an opinion, but it would solve your issue.

Comment: @Pierre-LucPineault the example is somewhat contrived, and strives to illustrate that the class itself is simply a convenience class (which is why it's named facade). I'm primarily concerned with where that enum belongs. Unless I am misunderstanding your comment regarding polymorphism.

Comment: @Pierre-LucPineault - this supports the use case when you want two fast calls, and then an accurate one using the same instance...

Comment: The actual implementation uses an IActionFactory which takes a configuration object and creates the concrete actions opaquely. But again, not really the point here.

Comment: @EBrown I would be firmly against that convention. They are not Types (they are enums) and nowhere in the framework is such a suffix used (that I am aware of.

Comment: @Michael Well from the looks of it it really seems like a kind of Strategy Pattern, where you could switch the action modes.

Comment: It is, very much so. But I'm concerned with the enum declaration and its effect on the public API, in a general sense. The example is just illustrative.

Comment: @Pierre-LucPineault, really not seeing how this is in any way a case for polymorphism.

Comment: Why does the enum need to be nested? So what if it's only used by this class? Don't nest it and then you can declare `public ActionMode ActionMode ...`

Comment: @DavidArno Yeah, didn't care to delete the comment after looking more thoroughly at it. It's actually pretty much like an enum-based strategy. The question would also be a good fit for Code Review, there's already [a similar question](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/58489/strategy-pattern-instances-based-on-enums) for Java.

Comment: @DavidArno that really is the crux of the question. Certainly it doesn't need to be nested. I was wondering if there was an accepted convention, and reasoning behind. I've elected to put it outside the class. Are you aware of a situation where a public nested enum might be appropriate, out of curiosity? In particular, where there is also a member of that enum type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems much more common to place the enum outside the class. Keeping it inside means you will end up needing to specify ClassName.Enum everytime you set the mode:

```
var mma = new MultiModeActionFacadeObject(fastAction, accurateAction, intermediateAction)
            {
                Mode = 
                    MultiModeActionFacadeObject.ActionMode.Accurate
            };
```

Also, since either way is valid, I don't consider this a definitive "answer". I would have just added a comment on your original question, but that requires 50+ rep :)

Comment: Well, now you can comment. :) I elected to go this route, as it is certainly most common, what I am generally used to doing, and I can't find any evidence supporting the alternative.